Strong maximum principle proof
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a non-empty, open, connected set, let $u\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ (harmonic function) and $x_o\in\Omega$ such that $u(x_o)$ is the global maximum. Then $u$ is constant on $\Omega$ and $\forall x \in\Omega: u(x)=u(x_o)$.
Proof:
Let $U= \{x \in \Omega:u(x)=u(x_o)\}$. Then $U$ is clearly closed. If we prove that $U$ is also open, then because of the fact that $\Omega$ is connected we get $U=\Omega$.
For $x\in U$ we get by the mean value theorem:
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{|U(x,r)|}\int_{U(x,r)}u(y)d\lambda(y)$$
which yields
$$\frac{1}{|U(x,r)|}\int_{U(x,r)}u(y)-u(x)\;d\lambda(y)=0$$
therefore $\forall x \in U(x,r): u(y)=u(x)$ and $U$ is open.
I'm trying to understand the proof and I don't see why U is clearly closed.

The set $U$ is closed because $u$ is a continuous function, and the level set $\{x\in\Omega:u(x)=u(x_0)\}$ is the preimage under $u$ of the closed set $\{u(x_0)\}\subset\mathbb R$.
It is one of the equivalent characterizations of a continuous function that the preimage of a closed set in the codomain is closed in the domain.
